# I can't connect to localhost 5000, when I try to load the page, It says that It can't access the site

Tags: javascript

I specify the port in .env file.
In the result I expect to see "{message:'WORKING!'}" on the page, but It just can't open the page
There is a code in index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const models = require('./models/models')
const cors = require('cors')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json)

app.get('/', () => {
   res.status(200).json({message:'WORKING!'})
})

const start = async () => {
   try {
      await sequelize.authenticate()
      await sequelize.sync()
      app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Port ' + PORT))
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
   }
}

start()
```

And in .env I have written PORT=5000

Comment: Can you add a ss of the error are your getting?

Comment: Don't add a screenshot, always add actual text.

Comment: Tried another port? 5000 could be used by other applications as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

Comment: @debugger please don't post random guesses

Comment: 1. `app.use(express.json())` 2. `app.get('/', (req, res) => {` flagging this as typos